# Expression Engine Counting Entries in loop

Tags: php, loops, expressionengine, counter

So I need to count how many entries are being pulled for a certain group.  Heres my code dumbed down.

```
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
{exp:weblog:entries related_categories_mode="on" custom_fields="on" orderby="view_count_one" sort="desc" limit="4" offset="0" weblog="{my_weblog1}" start_on="<?php echo $current_time; ?>" }

      <table>
        <tr valign="top" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <td> {if weblog == "Newsroom"} <a href="{title_permalink="freedom/articles}">{if Image}<img src="{Image}" >{/if}</a>
            {if:elseif weblog == "Health Freedom"} <a href="{title_permalink="freedom/articles}">{if Image}<img src="{Image}" >{/if}</a>
            {/if} <br /></td>
          <td> <h3>{if weblog == "Newsroom"} <a href="{title_permalink="freedom/articles}">{title}</a>
            {if:elseif weblog == "Health Freedom"} <a href="{title_permalink="freedom/articles}">{title}</a>

            {/if} <span class="date">&ndash; {entry_date format='%m/%d/%Y '} </span> </h3>

</td>
        </tr>
<?php $i = $i++; ?>
      <?php $count = '{count}';   ?>
<?php echo $count;?> {/exp:weblog:entries}
<?php echo $count; ?>
<?php echo $i; ?>
```

So basically during the loop it counts up to 4 with $count, but ontside the weblog I get 1 for $count and 0 for $i .  Can someone help me?  I should also mention the php is being rendered on input.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php $i = $i++; ?>
```

To

```
<?php $i++; ?>
```

The way you have it is setting new `$i` to old `$i` and then incrementing old `$i` (which no longer exists).

Comment: I still only get 1.  The problem is the php is being rendered before the weblog loop.  But still I get a count of 4 with my $count variable but as soon as I take it out the loop I get 1.  It only sees it once in the loop and takes it...is there some way I can set the variable only on the last iteration?

Comment: or somehow make that php variable be delayed until after the ee code is rendered?

Comment: well the expression engine code is looping through 4 entries....I understand my code is faulty, I just have no idea how to fix it

Comment: I know!!! the problem is it is reading the php first so the loop is happening after the php is set

Comment: there is an option to make the php set after the ee, but this makes it so other parts of my code wont work.....I think I might need an include